# How to calculate fractional years in MySQL

Tags: mysql

What's the best way to calculate a date difference in fractional years?

```
year(date1) - year(date2) always gives a whole number
```

Using unix_timestamp will give different values for leap and non-leap years (that is, March 1, 20NN to March 1, 20NN+1 should always be 1.00 years). I could break down the dates into months and days and, in effect, do it by hand.

But I'm looking for the best way - meaning easiest and requires the least debugging time (if I did it myself, I'd spend half the evening testing edge cases).

Comment: did you try casting to float/decimal or something?

Comment: @tpaksu - year() is defined to return the year part of a date or datetime, so the difference between two years will always be a whole number.

Comment: `select datediff(curdate(),'2000-01-01')` gives you the day difference. and when you divide it by 365.6, you'll get the fractional years I think.

Comment: Sorry, divide it to 365.25. 6 is not right.

Comment: @tpaksu - I think you missed the part where I said that I need something that is consistent across leap years. Your denominator of 365.25 is only approximate and would yield different results depending on whether there were leap years in the interval.

Comment: `datediff` will give you the day count with considering the leap years.

Comment: How are you intending to use the result of this calculation?  I suspect your premise is wrong (and you're going about the underlying problem in the wrong way), because this isn't really meaningful.

Comment: How can the conversion of an interval between two datetimes be wrong? That's a rather arrogant statement, wouldn't you say? What I am doing is simple: trying to express an interval of time in decimal years - that can't be any more wrong than expressing an interval of time in seconds or any other unit of time. It is complicated by the fact that the unit doesn't stay the same size - and I'm working my way through that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are going to find a simple way to do what you are looking to do.  In order to convert to some decimal value, you have to understand what the numerator and denominator are going to be.  As you yourself pointed out, the denominator will vary from leap years to non leap years.  That would leave you having to define which exact days in the year have a denominator of 365 and which have a denominator of 366 (i.e. do all days from Jan. 1 to Dec 31 in leap year have denominator of 366, or does denominator of 366 run between Mar 1 of year before leap year to Feb 29 of the leap year?).

You would than have to sum up every single day's value (1/365 or 1/366) for each day in your range.  Say you defined the start of the leap year as Jan. 1 - this still wouldn't give you an exact value of 1 for Mar 1 (leap year) - Mar 1 (non-leap year), since some days would have denominator of 365 and some with 366.

If you defined denominator of 366 starting on March 1 of year before leap year, then you should get exactly one for the Mar 1 - Mar 1 case, but what now happens when You want to do Feb 1 (leap year) - Aug 1 (non-leap year).  You are not going to get exactly 0.5 now for this 6 month difference.

My guess is that you might best approximate your math by doing something like

```
ROUND(( DATEDIFF(date1, date2) / 365.25), 2)
```

This will give you 1.00 for 365 day differences (365/365.25 = 0.9993) and for 366 day differences (366/365.25 = 1.0021)

Of course this also means that Mar 2 (non-leap year) - Mar 1 (non-leap year) will also give you a value of 1.00. But if your precision is two decimal places anyway that is the value you would receive using 365 as a denominator (366/365 = 1.0027)

Our calendar system is not really conducive to doing math against it, so oftentimes, you just have to live with a reasonable approximation and understand its limitations.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like:

```
select datediff(curdate(),'2000-01-01') / 365.25
```

?